# How to create a network graph from a dataset using colab?

Tags: pandas, google-colaboratory, networkx, network-analysis

I successfully uploaded the edges file of my dataset but how can I create the network graph?

[image: the uploaded data]

Comment: Checkout networkx's [from_pandas_edgelist](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html?highlight=from_pandas).

Comment: @QuangHoang this is for directed what if undirected graph like the attached data without source and target?

Comment: Networkx has  both `DiGraph` for directed and `Graph` for undirected. The function uses `Graph` by default.

Comment: @QuangHoang can you assist with example of how can I write this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's `networkx`:

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

# note that your file doesn't have column names
# passing `names` to label the columns
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', names=['a','b'])

# don't worry about `source` and `target`
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='a', target='b')
```

Then `G` is a bi-directional graph instance.

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate your help